# Calls within callback do nothing

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, callback

I am trying to make a call to another function from a callback but it does not do anything even if the callback is executed. What can be?

This is React Native, although in this payment gateway code there is no JSX involved:

```
 var conektaApi = new Conekta();
        conektaApi.setPublicKey('key_CWraZrrnBCZ5aFP6FtYNz9w');
        conektaApi.createToken({
        cardNumber: '4242424242424242',
        name: 'Manolo Virolo',
        cvc: '111',
        expMonth: '11',
        expYear: '21',
        }, function(data){

            this.callAnotherFunction()
//I also tried anonymous function and arrow
// ()=>{ callAnotherFunction}

        }, function(){
        console.log( 'Error!' );
        })
        }
```

In no way am I succeeding in having another function executed in case of success. In github you can find the js code of the Conekta module, which is a very simple code in reality but I can not deduce what is happening or how to fix it.

I think the problem is in the index.js of the dependency of Conekta:

[Conekta module js](https://github.com/zo0r/react-native-conekta/blob/master/index.js)

This contains the index.js of Conekta:

```
/**


* @providesModule Conekta
 */

'use strict';

// RNConekta
const RNConekta = require('react-native').NativeModules.RNConekta;
const Platform = require('react-native').Platform;

var Conekta = function() {
    this.publicKey = false;
};

/**
 * Params:
 * publicKey: String (Your testing or production Public Key)
 */
Conekta.prototype.setPublicKey = function(publicKey: String) {
    this.publicKey = publicKey;
};

/**
 * Params:
 *  info = {
 *      cardNumber: String
 *      name: String
 *      cvc: String
 *      expMonth: String
 *      expYear: String
 *  }
*/
Conekta.prototype.createToken = function(info: Object, success: Function, error:Function) {
    info.publicKey = this.publicKey;

RNConekta.createToken(info, function(response){
    if ( Platform.OS === 'android' ) {
        success( JSON.parse( response ) );
    } else {
        success( response );
    }
}, error);
};

module.exports = Conekta;
```

Comment: Are you sure method callAnotherFunction() belongs to 'this'?

Comment: I'm not sure about that, how do I verify it?

Comment: I put this.callAnotherFunction.bin (this)

And arrow function => this.callAnotherFunction ()

None of that has worked

Comment: How is the function defined that you want to run? If I'm not sure what this is reffering to I just console.log it

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with Conekta but I think you need to specify a parameter for an error too in your **`function(data)`** line like this:

```
function(err, data){
    if (err) {
        console.error(err);
        return;
    }
    this.callAnotherFunction()
}
```

Comment: In the index.js of Conekta says that if there is data then return sucess, otherwise return another error function.